# Remove all html tags and keep spacing between words?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a Helper method that removes all HTML tags:

```
    public static string StripHTML(string input)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(input, " <.*?>", string.Empty);
    }
```

The string looks like this:

```
<p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p><b><br></b></p>
```

When the helper method has done it´s thing, the string looks like this:

```
TestTestTest
```

What i want is to keep spacing between each word ... like this:

```
Test Test Test
```

How can i get around this?

Comment: `Regex.Replace(input, @"\s*<(/)?[^<]*>", m => m.Groups[1].Success ? " ": string.Empty).Trim();`.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor ... works perfectly :)

Comment: Actually, it won't work nice in other scenarios. Did you try solving it with `XElement` or `HtmlAgilityPack` (or any other (X)HTML parser)?

Comment: No i have not tried solving ths issue with XElement or HtmlAgilityPack!

In which scenario´s will this fail? :)

Comment: I have posted an answer showing how you can collect all node values with HtmlAgilityPack and join them. Really, if we compare the two solutions, the HTML parser looks more readable and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) that should work with any HTML you feed it:

```
var result = joinCleanNodeValues(input, " ").Trim();
```

And here is the method:

```
public string joinCleanNodeValues(string html, string separator)
{
    var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument(); // Load the HTML 
    doc.LoadHtml(html);                           // Build the DOM
    var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes       // Go thtough the nodes
        .Select(p => HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(p.InnerText))
        .ToList(); // Collect inner texts with all entities converted to literal texts
    return string.Join(separator, nodes);         // Return the joined node values
}
```

Note that the regex solution I showed in the comments might fail if there are multiple closing tags on end. If we go on adjusting that regex solution it might just turn out unreadable or hard to maintain.

Comment: I have installed HtmlAgilityPack via the packet manager console, but cant seem too find the reference ... any idea?

Comment: It is not necessary to use the using directive with my snippet, I am using fully qualified names. After installing the package with NUGet, you can just use the code. At least I had no issues with that.

Comment: Ok ... i will try to find a fix for this error :)

Which version are you running of HtmlAgilityPack? Im on 1.4.9

Comment: I fixed it ... all is working perfectly ... thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use HtmlAgilityPack as Wiktor suggested, you can also do something like this:

```
public static string StripHTML(string input)
{
   HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
   doc.LoadHtml(input);
   return string.Join(" ", doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[text()]").Select(node => node.InnerText));
}
```